# How to hide API key in a js file, i am using " axios" for requesting a url from js file and my application is not node based

Tags: javascript, api

How to hide API key in a js file, I am using " axios" for requesting a URL from js and  my application is not node based, so we can't use `.env` here.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you tag nodejs if its not node based? What else is your js running in?

Comment: You cant hide it from the client since java script is ran from the client side. You could encrypt it, but wouldn't be to hard for someone with the correct knowledge to decrypt it.

Comment: I had a js file  (app.js)  in root directory which is node based, i had used  ".env" there but this JS file (page.js) is particularly for a .ejs file, is there any way we can implement .env in page.js from app.js

Comment: So you _are_ using Node... Your problem is unclear. Of course you can read the .env file from anywhere in your server, use the `dotenv` npm module

Comment: Anyway, there is no way to fully hide/encrypt something that runs in a browser. Everything there is public. If you send a "secret" key to a client, it won't remain secret for very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your API keys in something like a "config.json" file in a json format and import that file to your js to access the keys. This file should only reside on your server and not in your repository. Like you stated its impossible to use the .env file outside the node environment in a js project